# Querystring integer value: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting the "Input string was not in a correct format." error because I'm trying to set the following variable to a value from the querystring:

```
sentFolder = Request.querystring("fid")
```

Can anyone briefly tell me how I can get the querystring and convince this thing of it's intended datatype: An integer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Integer.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) to convert a string into an integer:

```
Dim sentFolder As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(Request.QueryString("fid"), sentFolder) Then
    ' sentFolder now contains fid as an Integer. Do something with it.
Else
    ' fid has not been a valid integer. You might want to raise an error here.
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use int32 or a different integer type depending on what values your fid might go up to. for example, if the fid might be trillions, 1,000,000,000,000 then you might consider to use int64.

but [data type . parse should have you cover.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx)

so for completeness sake:

```
sentFolder = Convert(Request.querystring("fid"))

Private Sub Convert(value As String)
      Try 
         Dim number As Integer = Int32.Parse(value)
         Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number)
      Catch e As FormatException
         Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", value)
      End Try 
   End Sub
```

Comment: Apparently that technique produces the "Expression does not produce a value." error.